# sql select two tables with foregin key

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

I want to combine two tables into one.
First one is:

```
ID    code_1      code_2
==============================
1      XXX        YYY
2      ZZZ        YYY
3      YYY        ZZZ
```

Second one is:

```
CODE    Name
==============
XXX     Name_1
YYY     Name_2
ZZZ     Name_3
```

There ist a FK code_1= CODE and code_2 = CODE 
I want to create a table just with Name_1 and Name_2( by code_1 or by code_2)
but not just a smiple query where instead of names are XXX or YYY but with the Names from FK. Like this:

```
ID   code_1    code_2
=======================
1    Name_1    Name_2
3    Name_2    Name_1
```

I tryed so, but I don't known how to replace XXX with a Name_1:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.code_1, Table1.code2 FROM MyDB.Table1
WHERE (code_1=XXX and code_2 =YYY) or (code_2=XXX and code_1 =YYY)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why only two rows in the answer? You're not just replacing codes by their names. What are you doing? Please say more about when a row is in the answer. (You must tell us what you are summarizing/labeling as "combine".) Ideally, finish this sentence template: row (id,code_1,code_2) is in the answer when (f.id,f.code_1,f.code_2) is in First and (s1.code,s1.name) & (s2.code,s2.name) are in Second and id = f.id and and code_1 = s1.name and code_2 = s2.name and s1.name = f.code_1 and s2.name = f.code_2 and ..."

Comment: PS Read re SQL JOIN. The join of two tables given aliases a & b are the rows that are a concatenation of a row from a and a row from b. (A sentence template AND leads to an SQL query JOIN, ON, WHERE or AND.)

Comment: PS Please read & act on [mcve]. Not giving one, ie the info relevant to answering your question, makes your question off-topic.

Comment: Your edit is not clear. "Simple query" is another label, not an unambiguous description. "Not just a simple query" is another label. Use enough words and sentences to explain clearly. (One is enough: the sentence template aka *predicate* I asked for earlier.) (Your explanation must account for only ids 1 & 3 being in the example output.)

Comment: Maybe you are trying to say that you want the unique rows that look like a row of First that has code_1 and  code_2 both in {YYY,XXX} but with each code replaced by its name? PS If a table (key,...,x_1,x_2) can be replaced by (key,...,,n,x) or (key,...,x) then it usually should be. Otherwise queries & updates are needlessly complicated. Eg likely the first table you really need is (id,n,code) and the result you really need is (id,name).

Answer (score 0):

To get a result that includes both tables you could use:

```
SELECT id FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON CODE = code_1
UNION ALL
SELECT table2.name Name1
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON CODE = code_1
UNION ALL
SELECT table2.name Name2
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON CODE = code_2;
```

> The above is not tested. Let me know if it helped.

*For more info on MySQL, you could check out: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/*

> **UPDATED**

Comment: Yes it it but just one case XXX and YYY not YYY and XXX

Comment: One needs to know what the tables mean in order to query. One does not need to know the constraints. One might use the constraints, eg to convert a 1-row 1-column table to a value or to leave out a DISTINCT or leave in an ALL. But one never *needs* the constraints.

Comment: @Kate What are we supposed to do with "I got syntax error"? Give the error message. Google the error message. Read about UNION.

Comment: and of coure CODE is PK and FK are also there

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich PS Don't forget sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: now i have just one column with ID and the values are the Name_1, Name_2, Name_3 so it isn't what i want

Comment: This is as close as it gets to what you want. Try merging Name_1 and Name_2 into 1 column, or change your conceptual schema

Comment: @Kate "just one case XXX and YYY not YYY and XXX" and "CODE is PK and FK are also there" and "values are the Name_1, Name_2, Name_3" are unintelligible.

Comment: @philipxy You don't have to be mean. I think I shouldn't have tried to help in the first place, because her question is just not good and had 0 effort put into it

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich I don't know why you think it is mean to tell someone that what they wrote is extremely unclear. Almost certainly they already know that it is unclear and likely extremely unclear. If hopes are dashed don't shoot the messenger. PS Suspect they want 1st joined twice to 2nd with the above filter then select id & names as codes. Possible alternate filter is ids where there's another id j where (code_1,code_2) is (j.code_2, j.code_1). Agree re 0.

Comment: @philipxy You are correct. I put too much effort in helping Kate when I shouldn't considering the effort she put into asking.